# How to limit the number of records saved in a day in ASP.Net Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a patient booking system using ASP.NET.
I want to limit the number of bookings to 25 per day.

Using a suggestion, I have obtained the following SQL Trigger Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_CheckAppointmentCount ON dbo.schedule_master AFTER 
INSERT,UPDATE
AS BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM dbo.schedule_master YT
           WHERE YT. Schedule_Date IN (SELECT i Schedule_Date FROM inserted)
           GROUP BY YT. Schedule_Date
           HAVING COUNT(YT.KeyColumn) > 25)
    THROW 50012, N'Cannot have more than 25 appointments on a single day.', 16;
END;
GO
```

But I don't have a KeyColumn. Please suggest any changes.

Comment: Could you provide any pieces of code you've tried so far? What about your domain model and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would better handled in the SQL Server side of things, in my opinion. you won't be able to do this with a `CONSTRAINT` but you could use a trigger. This is Pseudo-SQL, but perhaps something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_CheckAppointmentCount ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.YourTable YT
               WHERE YT.DateColumn IN (SELECT i.DateColumn FROM inserted i)
               GROUP BY YT.DateColumn
               HAVING COUNT(YT.KeyColumn) > 25)
        THROW 50012, N'Cannot have more than 25 appointments on a single day.', 16;
END;
GO
```

Comment: I don't have a KeyColumn. 
Using your solution, here is my SQL Trigger Code.

CREATE TRIGGER trg_CheckAppointmentCount ON dbo.schedule_master
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.schedule_master YT
               WHERE YT.Schedule_Date IN (SELECT i.Schedule_Date FROM inserted)
               GROUP BY YT.Schedule_Date
               HAVING COUNT(YT.KeyColumn) > 25)
        THROW 50012, N'Cannot have more than 25 appointments on a single day.', 16;
END;
GO

Please check and comment on this.

Comment: I can't read that SQL in the comments, sorry. Comments are not the place for it.

Comment: I have edited my original question. Please refer it.

Comment: If you do not have a key, then count a different non-`NULL` column, @FlaSh9293 .

Comment: I used Schedule_Date Column in place of KeyColumn which is not null. But, for i.Schedule_Date it shows an error "The multi-part identifier 'i.Schedule_Date' could not be found"

Comment: try now, @FlaSh9293 .

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why would you limit the number of booking; However; this can be acheived just by a simple counter in your backend system. Perhasps some configuration of max record so that you can change it in future rather just limit it to 25. So get the total records created while new booking is getting created; and if it's > than config limit ( in this case 25) , just display a message back to the user.

Hope this helps you to build the logic.